# Continue playing after the ending

Tags: far-cry-5

After the game has officially ended, regardless of which path you chose in the mission, is it possible to continue playing?

If so, how? Hitting "Continue" from the main menu just boots me back into the final part of the ending sequence and almost immediately goes to the end credits (again).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should apparently be able to continue from the last save as if the ending hasn't yet happened, and that being stuck in the "ending loop" [is a bug](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1861756-Continue-playing-after-last-mission?p=13411004&viewfull=1#post13411004):

> Sorry to hear that you've encountered this issue. After you finish the game, you should be able to continue exploring from your last save. The team is working on a solution and this problem will be fixed in a future update.

Comment: Note: you don't load from your last save. You load from a post-ending save (the final mission is marked as completed on your map).

Answer (score 6):

the thing that fixed it for me is: as soon as you spawn go to the map and fast travel to another location and after that it should come up with the credits again and once you hit continue one more time it spawned me on top of the radio tower on dutches island and i could continue.
(the background of the menu should also change)

Answer (score -4):

Just restart the game, it's workes for me...